# Unity project on iPhone - Lost connection to “iphone”, Restore the connection to “iPhone” and run “ProductName”

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

Although I have seen some questions related to this problem, all the solutions do not fix my problem. I try to 
Select Debug->attached to process->lanuchd(1). 
But when I select that option, it will show

```
Could not attach to pid : “1” unable to attach
```

This is a unity based iphone App, and I am not running this app on the simulator, I am running in on the real iphone. Can any one help!!!! I a confused for a long time QAQQQ Really need help.

Comment: When I run another xCode project, every things works fine... Except this project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem... It is because the high resolution of my image. When I use the lower resolution image, it works. Hope it will help.